# php correctly convert between encodings

Tags: php, unicode

I've just spent the last 3 hours tracking down a display problem on one of my pages. The text was a garbled mess. The problem turned out to be the use of `utf8_encode` on an existing utf8 string. [As noted in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php#104906) it can only convert ISO-8859-1. Why does it have such a misleading name? /rant.

What is the proper, less error prone, way of detecting and converting encodings in PHP?

Comment: if the string is already utf-8 you don't need `utf8_encode()`. in fact it will produce garbage as the string will be encoded twice. just do *nothing* and all is fine

Comment: "Why does <insert almost any PHP function> have such a { misleading, inconsistent, misguided } { name, implementation, documentation }?" Good question.

Comment: It can’t see how utf8_encode would mislead to think that is was to be used on content that is _already_ UTF-8 encoded …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) or [`iconv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php), depending on what's installed on your server. (iconv is enabled by default, however, mbstring is not.)

Comment: It looks like I may be able to kill two birds with one stone by using `iconv` and it's transliterations. How does it handle malformed strings? The standard \ufffe replacement?

Comment: With malformed strings (I'm guessing you mean invalid symbols,) it cuts the string at that point and generates an `E_NOTICE` error. If you append `//IGNORE` to the target encoding name, it ignores the invalid symbols.